# Inanimate object equivalent of “victim”

Tags: single-word-requests, word-usage

I am writing an article about a machine, that for a long time, was blamed for causing multiple fatalities as it was wrongfully believed that it had something mechanically/electrically wrong with it when in reality, the machine was in fact deliberately destroyed, and there was nothing wrong with it in any way.

Calling the machine in question a “victim” feels right as the machine in question was essentially sabotaged, but on the other hand, it feels wrong to refer to a machine in such a way.

Comment: Could you give the sentence in which you would use the word?

Comment: Got an answer? Post an answer. Do not answer in comments.

Comment: I don't understand. You're saying the machine was not to blame, but was sabotaged, which presumably caused it to malfunction and kill people. But then "there was nothing wrong with it in any way," so it couldn't have killed people unless its design meant that it would in fact do that, and in that case the blame is entirely correct. Which is it?

Comment: The example used in the question is confusing in that it involves two different kinds of arguable victimhood: (1) the machine being a 'victim' of sabotage, and (2) some people being the victims of the machine's malfunctioning (which was caused by the sabotage). The substance of the question concerns only the first kind; the question would be clearer (for the purposes of this site), if the second had not been mentioned at all.

Comment: Normally it would be fine to refer to the machine (or its reputation) as the *victim of sabotage* (or poor maintenance or whatever) linguistically/semantically this is fine to use. If your worry is not about the grammar, but rather that it will make you seem indifferent to the suffering of victims (and families) of the accidents and fatalities then maybe the word *target* would be a better option?

Answer (score 5):

You actually CAN call an inanimate object a *victim*, especially if you specify *of what*. As you point out yourself, a machine can be sabotaged. Here is an example from *[The Independent](https://www.independent.co.uk/news/sabotage-at-the-opera-house-1190547.html)*:

> The Royal Opera House has become the latest high-profile construction *project* in London to be the ***victim of sabotage***.

And another example:

> Despite theories that the *plane* may have been the ***victim of sabotage***, poor maintenance, or in-flight fire, investigators could not find enough evidence to support any definite conclusion.([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pan_Am_Flight_7))

If you are still apprehensive of using *victim*, then you can always say that *the machine was sabotaged*.

Comment: This is tricky. We often personify thus 'The storm was to blame for ...'. 'The machine was to blame for ...' is again often used for bad results where a machine is seen to be malfunctioning. But when sabotage was the cause of that malfunction, I'd stop using the personification as true blame is involved. Similarly, if there are true (human, usually) **victims** involved, as here, using the word in a personification is best avoided IMO.

Answer (score 1):

Without an example sentence, or even access to information about the event in question (for context), it's hard to be sure, but I'd suggest:

> **maleficiary,** *noun*: One who suffers harm from something.

Even though it's only in [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/maleficiary), it's resemblance to *beneficiary*, a more common word, makes its meaning somewhat self evident. You could see that the machine was a maleficiary. Equally, while I can't find any example sentences, its parallel, *beneficiary*, has been used for inanimate objects as well as animate ones. ([Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/beneficiary))

*The machine was a **maleficiary** of external sabotage.*

---

Speaking of sabotage: sabotage isn't a synonym for *victim*, as it doesn't represent an object (rather, even as a noun, it represents the action). Still, it could be useful. I'm going to paste the whole entry, as nearly all of the definitions are relevant.

> **As noun**
>
> **1**: `destruction of an employer's property (such as tools or materials)` or the hindering of manufacturing by discontented workers
>
> **2**:
> `destructive or obstructive action carried on by a civilian or enemy agent to hinder` a nation's war effort
>
> **3**: `a) an act or process tending to hamper or hurt | b) deliberate subversion`
>
> **As verb**
>
> `to practice sabotage on`

(From [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/sabotage))

How might you use this? It could be used as a verb, like *the machine was sabotaged by [whatever group carried it out],* or that it was *ruined by sabotage.* Or, put it together with *maleficiary* and get *the machine was a maleficiary of sabotage.*

The word for someone who *does* sabotage is saboteur, from French, but English doesn't seem to have borrowed the opposite word. See: [words starting with *sabot.*](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/words-that-start-with-sabot)

---

Other ways to set your sentence using those words:

*The machine was a **target** of sabotage*

> **target,** *noun*: a person, object, or place selected as the aim of an attack ([Oxford](https://www.google.com/search?q=target%20definition))

*The machine was a **casualty** of sabotage*

> **casualty,** *noun*: a person or thing injured, lost, or destroyed
> ([Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/casualty))

Comment: While the argument for using *maleficiary* is plausible when considered in the abstract, it seems risky to implement in practice, because the similarity of *maleficiary* to the better established *maleficent* is likely to mislead some people into thinking that it means the opposite of what is intended.